# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory

while opening visual studio 2012 showing error.

**ERROR:**

[image]

Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Maybe look at your Windows Event Viewer (see [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308427)). There might be an event logged by VS in there.

Comment: Check your c: drive. If its full this can cause problem. Or your RAM is less then 2 gb.

Answer (score 1):

Check your RAM status in Task Manager, too many programs running simultaneously can cause this exception.

If there is enough space available on RAM to run VS (1 GB (32 Bit) or 2 GB (64 Bit) RAM (Add 512 MB if running in a virtual machine)), Try re installing VS, If there's any update that is able to correct an issue like this, it's marked as important on Microsoft Update, so be sure to run it and select all the updates marked as important.

Also, check if running VS as administrator solves the problem, sometimes a normal user has some limitations (on business' networks it's possible that the IT limits memory usage by program, and windows 7 has some new security policies that I'm not sure how they work yet but running a program like administrator may solve your problem).